# Bottom Navigation View Size height up

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm using this code for my navigation bar

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu_sign_in_up"/>
```

The thing is that the height is totally messed up, when I set it to `wrap_content` as it is right now it adds like double the supposed height

and when I set it to a specific height the text and image just kind of join in each other
how do I solve it?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default icon size of the `BottomNavigationView` is ***24dp***.

It looks like, you set height of `BottomNavigationView` enough less for it. In that case, if you would like to decrease height of your `BottomNavigationView`, you should also change the icon size of the item.

Basically, you can use below feature in your XML.

```xml
app:itemIconSize="12dp"
```

So, your `BottomNavigationView` will seem like that:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:itemIconSize="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```