Android bottom navigation bar too big
The bottom navigation bar is too big. Looks fine in editor, but on device and emulator is too big. See attached photo:
bottom navigation bar
I have tried setting the margins and padding to zero, but to no avail.
Here is my code:
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp">


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Thank you so much for your help.

Duplicate of this perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415724/bottom-navigation-view-size-height-up

Yes thank you it had the answer.

This question is similar to: Bottom Navigation View Size height up. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
